# How to "lock" page contents in LibreOffice?

Tags: documents, libreoffice-writer

Example:

```
------------------------------
| Title                      |
| Subtitle                   |
|                            |
| Body                       |
| .                          |
| .                          |
| .                          |
| .                          |
| .                          |
| .                          |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
------------------------------
------------------------------
| LOCKED DOWN STUFF          |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
------------------------------
```

I'd like to find a way to lock down text on pages so that when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> several times without moving the `LOCKED DOWN STUFF`. I image in more technical terms, I'm asking if it's possible to remove the carriage returns between the end of `Body ...` and the beginning of `LOCKED DOWN STUFF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get You right - page break

```
Insert -> Manual Break.. -> Page Break
```

Is what You need. You can insert a manual page break with just pressin `Ctrl=Enter`.